# ExpressJS Router + Promise not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a problem with Express response and Promise.
My script call a MongoDB Database to get informations from the server. I use Promise to send the result only when my server answered me.

The problem is in my route. I get the response correctly, but the 
**res.send** returns nothing. I can't figure why.

Let's review my code. I've truncated some of the files, as it is not important code.

I have first a server.js file with my router declaration :

```
let router = express.Router();
app.use('/mongo', MongoRouter);
```

Then here is my MongoRouter.js file :

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { MongoController } from '../Controllers/MongoController';

class MongoRouter {
    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();
        this.controller = new MongoController();
        this.routes();
    }

    routes() {
        let obj = this;
        this.router.get('/global', (req, res) => {
            let promise = obj.controller.globalInfos();
            promise.then((value) => {
                console.log('Resolve OK. Showing data');
                console.log(value);
                res.send(value);
            }).catch((error) => {
                res.status(500).send(error.toString());
            });
        });
        this.router.get('*', (req, res) => {
            res.json({
                data: 'Invalid route'
            });
        });
    }

}

export default new MongoRouter().router;
```

And the function **globalInfos()** from my MongoController :

```
globalInfos() {

    var status = '';
    var globalInfos = new Array();
    var internalServerReached = 0;
    var dbCommand = {'serverStatus': 1};

    let obj = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        obj.cnxStrings.forEach(element => {
            MongoClient.connect(element['cnxString'], (err, db) => {
                if (!err) {
                    if (element['replica'] == true) {
                        dbCommand = {'replSetGetStatus':1};
                    }
                    db.command(dbCommand, (err, results) => {
                        if (!err) {
                            status = results;
                        } else {
                            status = 'Status unknown';
                        }
                        globalInfos[element['name']] = status;
                        internalServerReached++;

                        db.close();
                        if (internalServerReached >= obj.cnxStrings.length) {
                            console.log('Waiting 3s for the resolve');
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                resolve(globalInfos);
                            },3000);
                        } 
                    });
                } else {
                    status = 'Unreachable';
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

When i go to http://localhost:3000/mongo my function is running, the resolve is called after 3sec, my data are ok in the console (in the .then() callback), but the res.send(..) show an empty array **[]**

Thanks!